# One time snow removal

Tags: troubleshooting, winter

I rent in an urban area, so I don't own a shovel - weather almost never requires!  But the East Coast got hit with an unusual storm, and my car is snowed in.

**Is there a way to dig out my car without damaging it short of buying a shovel, to be used only once?**

Ideas that come to mind: rent a shovel, using some kind of sharing network, ask a neighbor, pour hot water.  I have called a few hardware stores (none rent) , can't find any share economy sites for this, and CL didn't have anything listed.  Suggestions?  Other info: hard snow, heavy, about a foot deep, ambient temp is ~ 40 F.  Thanks!

Comment: Shovel rental?! Seriously? - What is the price to *buy* one? Do you think sharing/renting could be profitable in any way? Given that most people happen to need the shovel *at the same time*...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about vehicle maintenance or repair

Comment: @Movemorecommentslinktotop  Sure.  You should probably close this [other similar, highly up voted question](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25238/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-of-getting-your-car-unstuck-from-snow) by the same logic

Comment: Use a bucket as an improvised shovel.

Comment: **Poor COLD water, NOT HOT!!**. If your windshield is sufficiently cold, hot water will crack it!

Comment: @DavidLively yes, I feel bad for that poor cold water too, not hot at all.  As for getting my car unstuck: there is no need to pour any water on the windshield of a stuck car...

Answer (score 1):

- **Door Mat Scoop** - Depending on how compacted the snow is that surrounds your car, you may be able to get away with using a doormat as an improvised snow scoop. This would be a good option (assuming you have one), especially if the snow has not long fallen.
- **Car Towing** - If you have access to another car (preferably four/all wheel drive), and you can access the car tow point you could use a tow rope to be able to apply a force to the car stuck in snow. Hopefully, this force will be enough to pull the car free before the wheels on the towing vehicle lose traction.
- **Hand Winch** - Along similar lines as the towing situation, but without the need for another car, you can consider using a hand winch. You need a secure anchor point and again the ability to access a secure towing point on the car that is stuck. There is a good post about these [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/25251/14003).

However, if I am correct in assuming that none of the above are a viable option for you due to your urban, and hence somewhat unprepared situation - you may also find some of [these tips](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/25246/14003) useful. I think that many of the tips I gave about how to get your car out of a snow bank would also apply to your situation because a lot of the points that were made there assumed that you had access to limited tools (though some didn't).