# My car broke down in Siberia. What do I do now?

Tags: repair, tools, parts

In a [Question on outdoors.SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/18740/11953) with the above title, gerrit's answer suggests "bring spare car parts to cover common faults".

**Aside from tire repair, fluids, fuses, wheelnuts, belts and hoses, what tools and parts could you bring to repair common mechanical failures that make the car undriveable**? (The referenced Question says "old car" in winter but I am asking about new cars in summer.)

Comment: Either read the book "long way round" by Ewan McGregor & Charlie Boorman or watch the series - I think the books give a list of what they took with them...

Comment: I'm voting to close as this is too broad. It's basically asking how to fix a car. Literally anything could break! If you could narrow it down to a single make, model and year and be a bit more specific on what the car would be doing it may be answerable.

Comment: I have to agree with @GdD. There is no one-size-fits-all answer, and even if someone did identify common failure points that make a vehicle undriveable in Siberia, how many of these could be addressed by an average driver on the side of the road?

Comment: @Zaid I'm just looking for any generic items I've missed on my short list, not specific to Siberia or particular make or model. Even "belts and hoses" is stretch for modern cars. In the olden days a fan belt was a feasible roadside repair and carrying a spare was commonly recommended.

Comment: Spare lightbulbs, zipties, hose clamps, duct tape, a block of wood, something for leverage and a healthy dose of ingenuity :)

Comment: @Zaid Maybe I should try to make a MacGyver question. Do they allow "[big-list](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list)" questions here like on math.SE? I carry baling wire. Sealing goop, "leak stop" and gasket material might be good. I have used electrical twist connectors but never thought to carry them, or wire, wirecutters, electrical tape, multimeter.

Comment: It can be made to work, but depends. Here's [one example](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/28188/675), and here's [another](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/28503/675)