# Does the oil level in my Pulsar 220 FI change the engine sound?

Tags: motorcycle, oil, pulsar, bajaj

I own a 2009 Pulsar 220 FI. When the engine is cold, the sound of the engine is pleasant. But when I run a few kilometers, the sound becomes harsh. I read that when engine oil gets hot the oil flows through the oil cooler and hence I think the oil level in the crankcase decreases which leads to increasing the harshness of the engine sound. The company specified quantity for engine oil is 1150ml and I have filled the same amount.

What will happen if I fill a few more 100ml of engine oil in it? What will happen?

Will it make the sound nice or will it damage my motor?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: define harsh.  Is it ticking or knocking?  Is it running rough, idling high/low, stalling, lacking power.

Comment: @rpmerf power is like 10% less and the  typical sound of old pulsars come by.. idling increases like as it should after the engine heats up. It hasnt stalled yet. Knocking sound also changes. I cant exactly describe you the sound but can record and share the link.

Comment: My friend has a hero honda cbz extreme. He recently changed the engine oil. So the level was perfect for his bike. He added a little more oil like a 50-100ml and found out that the sound at idle itself was reduced. I was just asking can i do the same for my bike and will it help me without damaging my engine. :/

Answer (score 4):

**50 to 100ml should be OK**

That small of an amount won't hurt anything in overall scheme of things.

Be careful not to put too much in though because you can do engine damage if you put in a large extra quantity.  You will want to ensure you do not overfill your bike beyond the high oil mark in your oil window on the side of your clutch cover.

This article talks about too much engine oil in a car and what the damage could potentially be but many of the principles also apply universally among all engines

- **[What actually happens when there is way too much oil in a car engine?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24679/what-actually-happens-when-there-is-way-too-much-oil-in-a-car-engine)**

**Sound Suppression**

I know that you indicated you have a friend that has experienced engine noise suppression by adding in an extra 50ml to 100ml of oil.  This will only increase the height of the oil by a millimeter or two in the crankcase, I do not see how this could increase sound suppression by 10%.

If you have sounds emerging from your engine that are of concern perhaps you have an issue that require addressing.