# Excessively over filled motor oil. Ran for a few seconds until smoke came out. Now my car won't start

Tags: oil, oil-change

So last night me and a friend changed the oil on my 2005 Chevy aveo. The only problem was that what we were draining was the transmission fluid and long story short we ended up adding about 6 litres of oil without draining out the oil that was already in the vehicle. As I was leaving my friends place I drove for about 10 feet when what looked like white smoke started coming out (although we decided it could have been a light blue but it was dark out.) and the whole vehicle started to rumble. now the vehicle won't even start. We figured out what we had done and drained the oil to an acceptable level but my car still won't start. I'm wondering if there is an issue that  caused by this that is fixable

Comment: Me thinks that you gotta clean the engine up from all the oil.

Comment: You did remember to refill the transmission oil before you tried to drive the car didn't you?

Comment: Let it sit overnight and try to start it in the morning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What actually happens when there is way too much oil in a car engine?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24679/what-actually-happens-when-there-is-way-too-much-oil-in-a-car-engine)

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe.  he's asking howto fix his situation and get the car started which is different than simply, "what happened."  Please retract the close on this.

Comment: Pull the plugs oil probably got into the intake through the PCV and the plugs are wet. If they are and you can see oil in the cylinders put some rags around the plug wells and crank the engine with the plugs out.

Comment: @DucatiKiller the question is whether "there is an issue that (is) caused by this that is fixable". All car issues are fixable, and issues that oil overfilling could cause are answered in that question. Honestly, I doubt it would be possible to answer how to get the car started without way more additional information either.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't see in your question where you refilled the ATF for the transmission. It's possible at least part of the grumbling you heard was the transmission complaining about being about 1/3 to 1/2 low on fluid. Be sure the use the right fluid as shown in your owners or repair manual for the car. Fill it back to the cold mark on the stick. I think an '05 Chevy will still have a dip stick for the transmission. Many newer cars don't, depending on the model.

Also, roughly half the volume of your oil is still dirty. Do the oil change again, but this time check what drains out to look for bits of metal in the oil. If you put a large, strong magnet in the pan that you're draining into, and make sure the oil drains onto / over the magnet, you can collect any ferrous metals in the oil. If you do find metal in the oil, do not attempt to start it again, take it to a professional for evaluation.

With that much oil in the crank case, cross your fingers your haven't destroyed the bottom end of your engine. If after filling the transmission, and making sure the oil level is ok, if you still hear horrible noises when you crank it, stop trying to start it. At that point you would be well advised to take it to a professional for evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't spend any more money replacing oil until you have got the engine running again.  Take the plugs out and check if they are covered in oil.  Make a note of which plug came out of which cylinder so you know which cylinder had the oily plug if there is one.  With all the plugs out, turn the engine over with the starter to blow any oil out of the cylinder.  I would then check the compression of each cylinder using a compression tester. If you have damaged one or more pistons, this should identify which ones. If everything looks OK, clean the plugs and put them back in and try to start the engine again.

Answer (score 0):

Methinks this sounds like a hydraulicked engine, boys... mechanic time! 
Ouch. Expensive learning experience. 
Too much oil in the crankcase can cause piston and conrod damage, ruptured oil seals and all sorts of of other mischief.