# Too much oil; now white smoke

Tags: ford, focus, smoke

Ford Focus Sport SVT Manual 5 speed transmission. I think I put too much oil in my vehicle. When I started to drive it there was no issue. After about 10 minutes. I started to see a cloud of white smoke come out from the tailpipe. After that I lost power when switching gears.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: This may be of interest:  https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24679/what-actually-happens-when-there-is-way-too-much-oil-in-a-car-engine/24681#24681

Answer (score 0):

Too much oil can be VERY harmful. See this.

http://www.t3atlanta.com/blog/car-tips/what-happens-if-you-overfill-auto-oil/

Comment: Nice link, but please include the relevant portion of the citation in your answer. Links tend to expire, and we try to keep the archive here as self-contained as possible for future users.