# My fiancé has over filled our van in oil

Tags: chevrolet

My fiancé has over filled our 2008 Chevy uplander by four quarts of oil. It’s now running very odd and an ass load of very stinky smoke is coming out the exhaust. We don’t have anything to siphon the oil out and I have to go get induced to have our baby in the morning. So I guess I’m asking is it okay to drive?

Comment: One does not typically "siphon out" oil. There's a drain plug in the oil pan under the engine. One empties out oil that way.  And NO, that much oil over normal is probably NOT good for the engine.  You're likely close to DOUBLE the amount.

Answer (score 2):

When this happens the oil gets contaminated with fuel. Completely drain the oil and get rid of it. Start with new oil. We lost an engine, it was an expensive lesson in life.

Answer (score 0):

If that is your only vehicle my opinion and recommendation would be to get a family member, friend, or ..Lyft, in that order, to give you a ride to the hospital in the morning, and deal with the vehicle afterwards.

I certainly wouldn't put additional miles on it in this condition, it'll only increase your risk (i.e. break down on the way, and/or permanent damage to the engine) or make things worse—find another option for tomorrow!

Of note: [What actually happens when there is way too much oil in a car engine](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24679/what-actually-happens-when-there-is-way-too-much-oil-in-a-car-engine)?