# Why is this valvetrain pitch-black?

Tags: engine, chevrolet, troubleshooting, ls1

I'm in the middle of an LS1 teardown.

Last weekend I removed the valve covers to and found it hard to see anything, as the pictures below will evidence.

While I wait for an opportunity to resume the teardown this weekend, I wonder what could be responsible for making the insides so black.

I can say that the residue feels hard, scaly and not very oily. There are some puddles of oil around a few of the valves, so I expect some of the valve stem seals to be shot, but would that alone explain the all-round blackness of everything in this valvetrain?

[image: Bank 2]

[image: Bank 1 Close-Up]

Comment: Can you give us some insight on the maintenance history of the car?
Perhaps also a photo of the dipstick's end?

Comment: Looks like it got very hot. Not sure. Interested to hear what it may be or what else you find as you continue your tear-down.

Comment: @CharlieRB you can follow the updates [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51715/zaids-lumina-diary)

Comment: [Do you remember this answer?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/24563/4152) ... while I don't know if this was a lack of oil, same thing applies. Craptacular maintenance done; craptacular results ensue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classic residue from an engine not worked too hard with low oil change intervals. Stripped and re-built 3 V8's which had that residue (all had done in excess of 100K miles). Took the block and reusable parts to a machine shop to get them cleaned in a chemical hot cleaner. Re-built engine went into a v8 short wheel base land rover (160bhp and quick...)

Comment: So is the residue oil or fuel?

Comment: @Zaid : residue is Oil. if it was fuel - then that amount over time would dilute the oil and it would seize rapidly...

Comment: @Zaid so budget for new hydraulic lifters straight off and camshaft...

Comment: This is a pushrod engine

Comment: Yes, and the lifters or hydraulic tappets sit directly on the camshaft between the pushrod end and the cam. At least it seems like that from what I see in the picture  - is this the first one you are taking apart?

Comment: Yes, this is my first engine teardown