# How do I know when I'm low on oil or need to do an oil change

Tags: nissan, oil-change, maxima, oil-level

I own a 06' nissan maxima and I am planning to  driving from Missouri to texas and don't know if I should get a oil change. When I check the dipstick, I pull it out and wipe it off, then put it back and pull it out again. The side of the dip stick has nothing on it but the plain side is full. So will it be ok to drive. And also what happens if there is no oil?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: [Here's the answer to your last question.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/24563/4152) As far as sticking the dipstick, try turning it over ... but realistically, you should see oil on both sides. You could be picking up oil off of the sides of the dipstick tube channel.

Comment: Are you checking the oil while the engine is running? If not, turn it off or you'll get bad readings.

Comment: When was the oil last changed? If last year, then get it changed before the drive just for peace of mind...